# Can you use the same bootable USB for multiple installations

Tags: live-usb

I'm trying to install Ubuntu on two laptops, but is it safe to use the same bootable USB for both, or should I burn the iso again?

My worry is if it saves configuration files or removes some files from USB during installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The installation USB does not store any installation-specific config files.
So, YES, you can use the same USB for multiple installations without any worries.

Comment: It worked, so you are correct!